# How Linux uses 3-level page tables for x86 CPUs with only 2-level page tables?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, page-tables

In the Linux documentation about page table management (https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html) is said the following:

> Linux instead maintains the concept of a three-level page table in the architecture independent code even if the underlying architecture does not support it.

and the following image is used to illustrate their three-level page table:
[image: Linux Page Table management]

Yet, x86-32 processors support only two-level page tables as shown in the following image:

[image: Intel 2-level page table]

Does this mean that Linux at initialization and when allocating pages uses its three-level page table while actually setting up the two-level page table of x86-32?
What's the point of using three-level page table? Only for re-usability?
This still applies for x86-64 four-level page tables?

When a page-table is required, who is actually doing it? Since the structure changes, my guess would be the OS. But can the OS actually see the internal structure of the page table of the processor?

Comment: Linux also has nommu.c for CPUs with no virtual memory.

Comment: *Yet, x86-32 processors support only two-level page tables* - You're forgetting about [PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), which only translates 9 bits per level instead of 10, so needs a small 3rd level in 32-bit mode.  But yes, if you're running on a truly ancient 32-bit x86 which doesn't support PAE, then hardware only supports a 2-level table.

Comment: Note that this is old information.  Gorman's book is about the Linux 2.4 and 2.6 kernels, circa 2003, and the three-level page table model is no longer current.  There is some info [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/106177/) about the transition to four-level tables, around 2004.  If this is a historical question about how 2.4 worked, that's fine, but if so you should clarify this in your question.

Comment: I read somewhere (can't find the link now) that they handled non-PAE x86-32 by simply inventing a dummy "third level page table" with only one entry.  So the kernel functions which would operate on the third level were basically no-ops, and the hardware only used two.  But even in those days, Linux supported other architectures which did have three levels, e.g. DEC Alpha.  So it made sense for the machine-independent framework to be based on three levels.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code but I think you are focusing on the wrong aspect. Both the software and the hardware (where the TLBs are walked by the hardware) need to use a hierarchical structure because it's sparse, otherwise the tables would occupy a large part of the memory. But in the end it's just a table: you put a page VA in and you get a page PA out. That's what matters for the architecture-dependent MM code. It gets asked to map a range starting from VA0 to PA0 and it does so using its own internal (i.e. CPU dependent) structures. The two table implementations are unrelated.

Comment: @margaret-bloom I don't agree they are just tables. The hardware accesses them and expects a given format. The two table implementations cannot be unrelated